# How did Wonder Woman change into her outfit work on the 1970's TV show?

Tags: dc, wonder-woman, wonder-woman-1975

In the 70's TV show, Wonder Woman changes into her garb by spinning around and a red ball of light flashes. Then poof, Lynda Carter is in her satin tights, ready to ensnare the baddie in her truth rope.

**Is there any in-universe explanation on how this quick-change phenomenon works?**

Comment: The Force did it. That red ball of light is actually made of highly concentrated Midichlorians.

Comment: It was smoking hot Lynda Carter in the TV show.

Comment: [The Evolution Of The Costume Change](https://thanley.wordpress.com/2010/11/27/the-evolution-of-the-costume-change/)

Comment: The flash was added after the pilot; https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=36&v=knEy_qqrxJU

Comment: Epilepsy sufferers look away now; http://www.newnownext.com/wonder-woman-spin-gif-wall/09/2014/

Comment: She is the same as you and me. She puts her subtley patriotic leotard on one leg at a time.

Comment: I like the original slow-mo, strip tease-esque version of the change better than the flash. Although I was only a kid at the time, it was the first time I thought about being tied up by a dominant and beautiful woman... Gotta love comics.

Comment: The original slow-motion cross dissolve effect was more complicated and, well, slow, so they came up with the flash to speed it up as well as simply it. The flash covers up the cut between Diana wearing regular clothes and wearing her superhero costume. My fanon explanation for the change in FX is that once she had some practice, she was able to change in a flash. :-)

Comment: @John Sensebe nice fanon explanation

Comment: It's Themysciran magic :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be an effect which was later incorporated into the comics without a real reason how or why it happens in-universe. Lynda Carter takes the credit for developing the spin for the TV show. And in a later flashback episode Diana's mother Queen Hippolyta teaches Diana how to transform her clothes magically into the uniform.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman_(TV_series)#Wonder_Woman_.281975-1979.29

A small clip which shows Wonder Girl remembering how she saw her mother teach Wonder Woman how to transform [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vej3b3LFV8)
The episode is "The Feminum Mystique part 1" from the first season.

Comment: Do you know the name of that episode, or better yet, find a clip of that scene?

Comment: @iMerchant: edited my answer.