# Where does Wonder Woman conceal her bracelets when she's dressed as Diana Prince?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-1984

A [recent question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/241065/how-does-diana-change-into-her-wonder-woman-constume-so-quickly) about how Diana quickly transitioned from her civilian attire to her Wonder Woman costume, in a scene from [Wonder Woman 1984](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7126948/), got me thinking about this. It appears that she wore the main body of her costume beneath her civilian clothes in the film, as she often does in the comics. She certainly wasn't wearing the bracelets prior to changing though, as her bare forearms were clearly visible in shots of her from just seconds or minutes earlier.

[image]

[image]

So where did she conceal the bracelets? And where does she conceal them in general when she's wearing civilian attire with short sleeves? Answers sourced from either the movies, comics or cartoons are welcome.

Comment: Presumably in the same place as the tiara?

Comment: The same Hammerspace pocket where she put that enormous sword in the first film

Comment: @Paulie_D - I considered asking about the tiara as well, but chose to focus on the bracelets, as those seem harder to explain. It could be that she simply has an out-of-universe 'magic pocket', like Immortals in the Highlander franchise, but I'm curious to know if this has ever been directly addressed in any medium.

Comment: https://allthetropes.fandom.com/wiki/Hyperspace_Wardrobe#Film

Comment: @Valorum, any particular reason to link allthetropes instead of TVtropes? Should I switch? https://allthetropes.fandom.com/wiki/All_The_Tropes:Why_Fork_TV_Tropes

Comment: @Valorum - Having reviewed the first film, there's actually no mystery about where Diana kept the sword. When she wore the blue evening gown, it was clearly visible on her back. When she removed the black fur coat she wore during much of the film, the sword was shown to be attached to her belt. And when she wore the grey suit in London, she handed the sword and shield off to Steve's secretary for safekeeping. So, no real hammerspace shenanigans involved, in the first film at least.

Comment: @LogicDictates - The sword hilt is sticking out of the back of her dress. When we see the sword later, it would have had to have been down around her knees and sticking *through* her buttocks. It's a 'neat' shot , but in reality the shot was filmed with only the hilt, precisely because of the problems of toting around a sword that big.

Comment: @Valorum - Regardless of how the shot was filmed in reality, we know where the sword was supposed to be in-universe, so there's no mystery in that regard. And they essentially acknowledged that Diana could not conceal the sword beneath regular, street clothes.